# Character Walk Cycle is not working properly

Tags: animation

i'm new to blender and just finished modelling and rigging my first character, then I started animating the walk cycle, I was going fine until I finished the first step, I further followed the tutorial I was watching and he duplicated the first step to make the second, so I did so and it just didn't work out for me:(
Here's the video:
https://youtu.be/gFf5eGCjUUg
and here's my .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_1jio7A29__dkI2Ti1aa2hSbms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: btw that video link is the tutorial, not my own animation

Comment: I think you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a names problem: as you can see the paste function is working for all "central bones", while the lateral ones need to find their side counterparts, and they can recognize them only with the right kind of suffix used for L/R.

For example if you rename your LeftFoot as Foot.L and your RightFoot to Foot.R, everything works properly for these two bones also.

Examples of valid separators:

```
(nothing): handLeft –> handRight
_ (underscore): hand_L –> hand_R
. (dot): hand.l –> hand.r
- (dash): hand-l –> hand-r
 (space): hand LEFT –> hand RIGHT
```

The Blender Manual states that also your way, with the complete Left or Right word before the name, should work, but it doesn't: you have to rename all your bones with an end L/R suffix.

Comment: I’m a bit confused, can you give me a link to what you did to fix my mistake.

Comment: Can you PLEASE give me the .blend file?

Comment: please, reply asap, i'm starting to lose my mind

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3919" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3919/) Just change the names of all your bones, adding a final suffix ".L" or ".R".

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer with the up arrow!